# Is it appropriate to ask a software developer about extra hours spent for side projects and open-source (as a hobby)?

Tags: interviewing, software-development

[Stackoverflow developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015) asked in 2015 about number of weekly hours dedicated to side projects / open-source outside of work (or programming as a hobby).

This is an interesting question and I am thinking of using it during the interviews for software developers positions (intermediate-senior level). This should provide an insight on intrinsic motivation of that particular developer. As a personal note, I find that intrinsic motivation is very important and that the company should strive more to find people that have it.

However, this might wrongly suggest working overtime and my company is very careful of not working overtime unless it is really needed and it is always payed appropriately.

**Question:** Is it appropriate to ask a software developer about extra hours spent for side projects and open-source (as a hobby)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78963/discussion-on-question-by-alexei-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-a-software-developer-a).

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I don't think it is inappropriate, but I would take care how you word this question. Make sure the interviewee understands why you are asking it. I once had a job where basically everything I did outside work was 'forbidden', so this question would make me hesitant if I didn't know why you were asking. There are companies out there that consider every line of code you write their IP, whether in your free time or at work. Other companies feel that, as a software developer, you have to use your free time to keep up with current developments, programming blogs etc. and that not doing this shows a lack of 'passion'. And everything in between.

Also, I do not think people that do a lot of side projects / programming as a hobby will necessarily be more intrinsically motivated *at work*. For me personally this doesn't hold up.

Comment: I'm genuinely concerned that anyone felt they had the right to control how employees spent their free time. Sure, there are some roles in which this might be seen as being appropriate - conflicts of interest  concerns for example, or if the person is in a position of public trust (e.g. police officer, judge, etc), but those jobs are few and far in between. Which country wasthis in and did they attempt to enforce this?

Comment: I'd also be afraid of a company that wants to know what I do outside of work. Some companies consider programming you do, on the clock or not, to be theirs. Others feel if you're going to code, you should be coding for them. And still others on the opposite side of the spectrum feel if you're not spending 4 hours at home on personal projects in addition to your real work, you're not passionate enough as a programmer! And all of them can take their opinions about what I can and can't do outside work and stick it in `/dev/null`!

Comment: As someone who has worked under a contract that essentially said "any code I write, on or off the job, is property of the company" that's a pretty solid way to kill programming side projects. It was also a solid push for finding a better company :)

Comment: @user1666620 it’s common in the US, and usually at the direction of legal consul.  It basically boils down to the fear of IP theft - I’d the same software developers who are creating your product also do side work, what’s to keep them from open sourcing your product, or keeping all the really good ideas they develop on company time and rushing off to strike it rich by founding their own company? This is an especially big concern IME with startups, who often get pressured to do this by investors/VCs. Enforcement is pretty lax, generally. ...

Comment: I actually once had an executive tell me “I just need your signature for [big VC investment firm], and don’t give a f—- if you actually follow the agreement... tell you what, list out any software side projects you have or are thinking about and we’ll call them pre-existing exceptions.” Which included total get-out-of-jail free cards like a side LLC, Github, etc.  IME, these things are like those legally worthless disclaimers some companies put at the end of email signatures - legally, they’re about worthless, but they’re also about free, and probably intimidate some ignorants into compliance.

Comment: As somone who codes for Fun and Games at home regularly, I can tell you from experience that no, it does not make me more motivated to work on Miscellaneous Data Entry Form #267.

Comment: I don't understand the negative reception toward the question.  I agree with this answer that it is both appropriate and that care should be given to wording.  I was asked this question at multiple interviews, felt open to give honest answers, and got the job both with "no I don't spend any time outside of work programming" as well as later on with "yes I spend a good chunk of time outside work programming".  I felt it gave the employer a better understanding of who they were hiring.

Comment: I think it's important to drill into the heart of what you actually want to know.  The specific number of hours spent on side projects is not important; what you really want to know is: does the candidate still express a natural curiosity and a desire to self-improve?  To this end, I think there are slightly better questions to ask.  In the past, I have asked candidates for their favorite programming blogs, asked what topics have interested them of late, if there are any recent books they have read which piqued their interest.  I think these questions are more 'innocent.'

Comment: @user1666620 If you were hiring an athlete to do 8hr running, would you be comfortable knowing that he doesn't come to work well rested, but instead keeps running in his free time? When it comes to me, after 8 hrs of work, more work will only make me more tired the next day.

Comment: @Agent_L if the athlete performs his job to your satisfaction, does it really matter? Poor performance can be corrected. No employer should be allowed to control what somebody does when they are not at work, particularly if they are not being compensated for it.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Makes sense - when I think of employees I want working for me, I think "ignorant and easily intimidated" too. Wait...

Comment: @corsiKa Right.  Not defending the practice, just... explaining why it exists.  Much like the email disclaimer thing, I find it contemptible and off-putting, but this is the world we live in.

Comment: @user1666620 Two problems: 1) it's easy to judge athlete's results. Programmer's result are much more intangible, often results are yield after months or years. Usually the fact that a task encountered no major obstacles is difficult to trace to good decision made half a year ago. 2) For most programmers it's physically impossible to deliver top performance for more than 6 hours a day. For my coworkers who took occasional sidejobs, the drop was noticeable even to me. Saying that one can perform at 100% for 10-12h is either delusional or asking for burnout.

Comment: @HopelessN00b it is NOT common in the US, and illegal in several states including California.  If given a contract with that rider, refuse to sign it.  Watch it go away immediately.

Comment: @user1666620: Pretty much every employed consultant (i.e. the employee of a consultancy) can be argued to conflict with their employer for _any_ side gig. The employer is effectively able to place developers on any contract; so every vacancy is technically part of the company's business interests. In spirit, that's not what the conflict rule is about, but to the letter it is, and I've seen colleagues gen into trouble for side gigs or even personal (commercial) products.

Comment: Regarding the IP clauses in contracts: it is worth pointing out that several states' laws either void these clauses or set strict limits on them.  For example, Kansas [Chapter 44, Article 1, Section 30](http://www.kslegislature.org/li_2012/b2011_12/statute/044_000_0000_chapter/044_001_0000_article/044_001_0030_section/044_001_0030_k/) states that a person retains ownership of work done on their own time with their own resources unless it relates directly to the business or results from work performed for it.

Comment: @user1666620 I have a friend who co-maintains a popular (1M+ a week) library with me and another friend. That friend joined Apple at some point. When they found out they did some open source he was forced to agree to stop commenting on GitHub and participating. While I completely agree with Dan above that the clauses are void - I agree with this answer that unfortunately some employers may view this negatively. Sabine, could you edit some of the points raised into the comments into the answer? (Comments are for clarification and don't exist  'permanently')

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaumI hate that sort of thing. "We want people who are passionate about software, who build applications in their spare time, who are involved in open source projects! But god help you if you do it when working for us."

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I will try and do that :)

Answer (score 165):

Would you ask a refuse collector if he cleans the local park on his days off for fun? Ever heard the phrase "Bus-drivers Holiday" (it means "Doing what you do for your work on your holiday")?

Side projects outside work are irrelevant. I've been a programmer for over 30 years. I know how to program, and if someone wants me to write a program, they're paying for it. I have a family and a full life outside work, and I'm not going to spend it throwing together some stuff on github just for an interviewer to drool over.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79062/discussion-on-answer-by-petecon-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-a-software-developer-ab).

Comment: The comparison to other occupations is irrelevant (many traits and habits are occupation-specific). That others "*have to pay you to program*" is a straw man. To me this sounds like you disagree with the premise of asking the question because you might be statistically discriminated against. You're not really answering whether it is appropriate to ask that.

Comment: PeteCon, I think that you dance around an important point here. You give all of the background without explicitly stating what FooBar has said: When this question becomes standard practice, those with families will have great difficulty finding jobs (definite discrimination). It is a sad state of affairs that folks have to devote 90% of their lives to coding just to be seen as a good employee. Whether coding outside of work is correlated to better employees remains to be seen, but it makes sense so it will exclude the family man from decent positions. I hope your attitude wins this argument.

Comment: Absolutely this. It is a discriminatory question. It is should never be asked.

Comment: @Joshu'sMu it doenst really exclude the family man from anything, they can still do programming in their (reduced) free time or just answer that they dont have the free time to do it anymore. I dont think many employers would care if you chose your kids over contributing to some github project.

Comment: There is something to be said about a person with 30+ years of experience who compares that life to a garbage collector. It's exactly the kind of candidate they want to weed out. Your implying that the question is offensive, but at the sametime you prove it's necessary. Your logic doesn't work for musician, painters or good programmers. I know plenty of 30+ year developers who are leaders of open source projects. You can't turn off passion, but what if you never had it.

Comment: @cgTag *You’re implying... 

Comment: @cgTag Yeah, it means that they day jobs are boring and unfulfilling. BTF, if you can't handle musicians and garbage handlers with one piece of code, you're not a programmer : )

Answer (score 88):

While I do not think the question is inappropriate, I also do not think it is going to give you the results you are looking for. Programming as a hobby does not necessarily directly correlate to intrinsic motivation. I say this as a very motivated software developer who does zero programming outside of work.

While I enjoy programming and am a motivated and efficient employee, I also have plenty of other hobbies that I want to pursue when I am not at work. Yes you can find plenty of developers who do program as a hobby, but you can also find plenty who don't, or don't very often. That doesn't mean they are less talented or won't be great employees.

As a comparison, I don't think many people interviewing accountants ask if their hobbies outside work include bookkeeping or payroll. Why does the same hold true of software developers?

I personally think that asking about a candidate's hobbies, interests, or passions can indicate their motivation more than "requiring" or expecting that hobby to be in a specific field.

Comment: +1. Interesting perspective. However, accountants + payroll hobby is not the same as programming as a hobby. Programming is way broader: e.g. I make web apps at work and spend some 2-3h/week toying with machine learning frameworks.

Comment: @Alexei very true! That comparison is fairly rough. My final sentence sums up what I was trying to get at but I had a hard time thinking of a good real-world comparison.

Comment: why not - many accountants will work as group finance person in their hobby groups, even if its only the local cricket team or dog fancier's association.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Can confirm. I am employed as an auditor and I frequently engage in financial/accounting/auditing topics outside of work. Local organizations often lack this kind of professional capacity and love to have the help.

Comment: @Alexei I'm a programmer while finances (including accounting) are my hobby. I assure, it's as just legit hobby as programming. Eg someone who does accounting for a corporation has very little idea how a self-employed programmer should file selling his old GPU. The accountant analogy is spot on: where programmers keep learning new frameworks and patterns, accountants keep learning new tax laws and interpretations of them. Almost every job is ever-learning, we're not as special as we think we are.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Absolutely, but you wouldn't think *less* of an accountant who doesn't do accountancy in their spare time. If you were interviewing an accountant who voluntarily does the books for the local cricket team, you'd think "This person is passionate about their local cricket team and generous with their time", ***not*** "This person is more passionate about accountancy than the other candidate whose free time is spent with their family and playing sports".

Comment: @user568458 And this exactly is the problem with such way of thinking: making up an artificial difference where there is none. Which is double troublesome when talking about programming, because programming is all about noticing similar patterns and extracting them into base code that can handle all cases in same way (as opposed to coding the same thing again and again every time anew) .

Comment: +1 Overall I think this is a better answer than the more higher voted answer because it gives the best explanation of the reasoning. However the one thing I disagree with is comparing programming to accounting. Programming is more comparable to being an artist or a garden designer - something someone might want to do outside of work because they enjoy doing it, or something someone might do as a hobby but not feel like they could do it as a job.

Comment: Serious question: never in your career have you had to solve a non-work problem via programming? I ask this because in my ~5 years as a software developer I've done that on several occasions, e.g. a CLI utility to convert Itunes playlists into Android-friendly formats with full unicode support (often missing in various others attempts at a solution). You've never had a programming problem of your own?

Comment: @Jared Smith I haven't had a problem that I've needed to solve with programming, but I'm also only 2 years into my software development career. I very well may run across a problem someday that I will solve using programming. However I still wouldn't particularly call it a hobby of mine. It's something I'm good at and enjoy doing for my career, but it isn't something I really do for fun (which is what I think of when I think hobby.)

Comment: @user568458-"but you wouldn't think less of an accountant who doesn't do accountancy in their spare time." You better believe I would think less of them. While I don't expect them to do "accounting for fun", I would certainly expect them to keep up with new tax laws and learn new techniques and loopholes. There's always something new to learn. The more the accountant knows the better the chance I'll be minimizing the amount of taxes I pay. Same goes for SW developers. The more they know, the better chance they'll be useful. How much one knows is directly related to time spent learning.

Comment: @Dunk, I expect an accountant to do that too but to do that during work hours. What a person does during their off time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 75):

### Would Not Ask Question As Stated

I don't see it as particularly appropriate or helpful.

Some people see hobbyist programming as a sign of passion, but some really passionate people put all their programming effort into their work. It's not a lack of passion, but a lack of time for outside projects.

There are potential privacy concerns. You have no way to verify a hobbyist's claims unless he provides access to his repository. But now you know his online identity (or at least have the ability to narrow it down substantially).

### From Personal Experience

I work closely with a department that has several excellent programmers in their ranks. One of them is your stereotypical open source fanatic, and he contributes to multiple FOSS projects---huge hobbyist. The other is a strong family man and doesn't code outside of work.

The bottom line is that hobby programming isn't a strong indication of passion and skill.

### Alternatively...

If someone has done top-notch work as part of their hobby, that is worth knowing. **Instead of asking if applicants program as a hobby, ask if they have worked on any projects they are particularly proud of.**

You can detect passion from the way they respond, and that passion could be due to either their work or their hobby. Plus, they can do this without worrying whether their hobby is under scrutiny or whether you'll push for excessive overtime.

**This gives you a natural lead-in for a followup question.** If they are proud of something, you can ask for details---and you could try relating it to work done by your company to sell yourself to the candidate. If they say they're not particularly proud of anything, then ask why not or what kind of work would they be proud to do. Again, you'll have an opportunity to sell yourself if your company has what they're looking for.

Comment: So many upvotes I wish I could give, because the last half of this answer gets at the heart of the matter

Comment: +1 The question should be phrased as an opportunity for the candidate to mention anything extra they wanted to talk about/they're proud of - and not as an additional criteria that judges people badly for not having out-of-work projects.

Comment: This is a strong answer. I like that you touch on what is my fear as a family man - that this kind of thinking will preclude me from advancing positions. I am have always surpassed expectation as a DB Developer, but when I'm not at work I try to be physically active so that my brain and body don't fail from sitting all darn day. I spend every minute with my kids when not at work (which may change when they're older). But questions like this really terrify me, because I value my free time and try to be a diverse human being, not a silo.

Answer (score 22):

You can ask about that, and in my experience it does positively correlate to people who are intrinsically motivated to program. People who love doing it will do it in their spare time.

***BUT***

It might not mean they're intrinsically motivated to work on *your* code, in your open-office, project driven hellscape. Some people really enjoy the freedom of hobby coding and if your company doesn't offer similar freedom (or other perks that are motivating but are unavailable at home) the motivation might not translate.

And perhaps more importantly, while most people who hobby code are intrinsically motivated, **the opposite isn't really true**. There are lots of people who would be intrinsically motivated who you're excluding with that question. Worse, the sort of people who hobby code tend to be the *same* sort of people. People without spouses or children to attend to after school. People who don't need that second job to make ends meet. People who can go to meetups or programming forums without being hit on and harassed at every turn.

In short, the question will significantly harm the diversity of your team (and candidates once it becomes broadly known). Given the downsides, I wouldn't recommend asking it, even though there's nothing strictly inappropriate about it.

Answer (score 17):

I used to think that finding a candidate with successful side projects was The Holy Grail of indicators. Nothing was a better indicator for success in a role than someone who demonstrated they could identify problems, research solutions, and follow that research through to completion *completely on their on passion and initiative* without leaning parasitically on anyone else.

"Now I know [I thought] we've found someone who is  good at all the technical parts of their job, not just a mindless hanger-on who was part of a successful team! We've got *a doer*, dang it! This is *their* code. This isn't a quick coding exercise. This is how *they* can work, showing what *they* produce."

The scary thing is that finding someone with great, complete, cradle-to-crave side projects really *is* a great indicator of individual ability.

**Unfortunately, looking for such side projects is replete with social bias, and the question, however useful it seems, is exceptionally unfair.**

@[Kozaky comes closest to saying why](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/114127/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-a-software-developer-about-extra-hours-spent-for-side-p/114140#114140), but doesn't take this far enough:

> Bear in mind that some candidates are simply incapable of taking on personal projects due to obligations such as family, travel, other hobbies etc. By all means, ask if they spend time on open-source projects but keep in mind that an answer of "zero" should not be a black mark. The technical test is usually how you can find out if they are keeping their skills up to scratch.

The argument is this: If my present situation doesn't allow me the time and space to have "hobbies", I'm not going to have time to make a great side project. Having time is a marker of exceptional privilege.

What do I mean by "not having time"? How about...

1. I'm working x > 1 jobs to put myself through school.
2. I'm working x > 0 additional jobs or working overtime in my 'extra' time to allow me to support my family.
3. I have family members whose care requires all of my non-work time.

   - Could be parents, spouse, kids, siblings, neighbors, friends... you name it

That is, I'm not just talking about people having things like kids, a partner, nearby family, religion, friends -- "a life" -- **your candidates could have *serious* backstories that are *none of your business***, pun intended.

And there are worse. Let's just mention one: "I'm abused at home." You won't learn this during an interview. In the US, eg, you *can't ask*, thankfully. But that's sure as heck going to stop you from completing la-dee-dah side projects.

I never really realized the amount of bias this question involved until a long Twitter thread pointed it out to me. If I can find it, I'll come back and add it. The point, and it's a point I think the other answers here largely miss, is that **assuming you have leisure time for *any* activity, much less time for coding is, let's kindly say, a classist assumption.**

You have to position your questions in a way to determine, "Does this candidate exhibit evidence they have the ability to fill this open position effectively?" based on fair, in-bounds experience. If they have relevant work history, you have to ask *specifically about their job*. If they have relevant school history, you have to ask *about what they did in school*.

**If you want to see them code a full project independently** (in place of an overly contrived tech interview), **you hire them as a contract worker to show you, and pay them handsomely for their time.** And I don't mean for a week. I mean for three months, or whatever the two sides negotiate. And note that "them" here isn't "someone without a side project". It's any serious candidate.
<sub>You also realize not everyone can drop whatever they're doing now to work for you on an interim basis.</sub>

If they offer side projects as evidence, I hope it's fair to keep what you learn "in scope", so to speak, as you debate merits later, and not necessarily punish people who are *privileged* and self-motivated for showing they *also* have the skills needed for your job, but you have, *have* to realize there are **much more motivated people** with practical, real-world priorities who will never put *takes care of father with dementia* or *cares for autistic child* as bullet points on their resume or use as topics of conversation in their interview.

And yes, this is a *very* difficult issue. Can you try and see if someone's a good teammate by encouraging them to share how they spend time with their coworkers outside of work? You could, but is it a fair measuring stick? Ultimately no, it's not. Your candidate could be the best coworker, but have much more important things to do than have the team over for dinner or hit a bar on Friday night.

So no, you can't ask that question, not in good faith.

Comment: Software engineering, particularly when it comes to the web, is an extremely fast-changing industry. Is it at all reasonable to expect employees to keep up outside of working hours? Probably not, but on the flipside, is it at all reasonable to expect employers to not hire someone who is more likely able to keep up over someone who isn't? At the end of the day, if the answer is "no because it's not fair because not every one has free time" as opposed to "no because it doesn't imply they are a better software developer" then I'm not sure why an employer should care.

Comment: If someone has a second job coding, that means they're getting more experience with programming than someone who comes home and does other hobbies -- they're in the same category as the person who does a recreational programming project. None of this is about being 'fair', it's about determining who will be the best employee for the company. Of course you want to phrase the question in a way that allows for answers like this.

Comment: @Charles -- I was assuming a case where some or all of the work being performed *wasn't* directly applicable to the current role. But don't miss the point for the examples. What's important is that there are *very important* reasons someone might not have free time. Could be a stocking job during 3rd shift, taking care of a loved one, or something "delicate" that's none of our business. "Fair" here means ensuring you don't penalize someone who'd be *excellent* at the job in the company's time (reasonable working hours) because they don't fit a *privileged* conception of an ideal coder.

Comment: @ruffin It may not be fair that someone working a second job stocking shelves is at a disadvantage to someone working a second job coding, but the person working a second job coding will actually be a better candidate, all else being equal. I used to work on coding projects in my spare time, and I no longer have spare time for them as I'm about to become a father. Fair or not, that will make me marginally less valuable as a programmer than I would have been otherwise.

Comment: @Charles I think we're talking past each other. I'm not arguing, "*the person working a second job coding will actually be a better candidate, all else being equal*" -- though I don't necessarily believe that's true (twice crap is still crap. Twice competence is still competence!). What's crucial is that *we determine fit in ways other than asking, "Do you have side projects?"* Asking about additional *related* jobs is fine. Asking @ what someone's gained by stocking shelves is too! But *idealizing best candidates as those with projects finished in their spare time* enforces a cultural bias.

Comment: @Charles I think what ruffin's saying (and correct me if I'm wrong, ruffin), is this is a kind of XY problem. We want the most qualified candidates (X). We *think* side projects are a strong indicator of that (Y). So instead of checking for X, we're asking for Y and conflating the two. But in reality, on top of Y actually being a questionable indicator, it's also skewed towards those with extra time in their life. So instead of just finding the best candidates, this question finds the best candidates *with spare time*. If that's the culture you want, sure, but I agree it's not in good faith.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I probably wouldn't use X & Y just to avoid gamete bias (though the more I think about it, it might be a great metaphor -- we're assuming Y is better, but is it? Do we really want a culture full of [just] Ys? ;^D), but that's absolutely money. **Perfect TL;DR for my answer**; thanks!

Comment: @EdmundReed, it is possible to keep up during work hours. It is unreasonable to expect people to do this outside of work hours in fact.

Comment: @HLGEM I think I agree; adequate time during work hours should be dedicated to "keeping up", as it were. At least 1 hour per day should be allocated to reading and researching in my opinion.

Comment: @Charles, this is wrong. Anyone who codes full-time can become a great coder without outside projects. I personally have known people who were terrible coders who also coded for a hobby. Reinforcing bad habits also happens. The assumption that you are better because you are a hobbyist is bunk.

Comment: @HLGEM Sure, it’s possible, I never claimed otherwise. But all else equal, more time coding will lead to a better coder, whether that means a full-time programmer being better (over time) than two part-time programmers, a coder with a second coding job, or whatever. And as a separate issue, I think passion counts for something, too. For example, though I couldn’t claim much time coding outside work anymore, having worked on various personal projects could demonstrate that I am passionate about programming, even though I don’t really have time for side projects anymore. What do you think?

Answer (score 10):

### This could be viewed as a "Gotcha question".

Many companies have a rule either prohibiting outside work, or requiring that you clear it with management.  In the old days, "outside work" meant moonlighting for another company: simple and understandable.  Today, the line is very much blurred - with volunteer projects, the ease of writing smartphone apps, and freelance job-matching websites.  If you're contributing to Firefox's image resizing engine, is that "hobby" or "job"?  How about your iOS Solitaire app that makes you $600/month?  The (trivial) programming required to keep your bitcoin miners running?

Certainly the applicant knows that many companies have an outside-work policy, and possible he's been burned in interviews etc.

So even though you're fishing for "job or lifestyle", the interviewee may think  you are fishing for red-flags that would disqualify him.  And of course he would find that very unjust.

Comment: "the interviewee may think you are fishing for red-flags that would disqualify him. And of course he would find that very unjust." - umm ... isn't that the entire point of the application process? How can that be "unjust"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper There are now rules on which questions you can and cannot ask (or to be more precise, discriminate against). As such, interviewees have cultivated a sense of "questions that make them feel uncomfortable" beyond the mandatory.  You bet an interviewer can ask a question which rankles the candidate or makes them seriously question working there, which is *not* the purpose of the interview.

Comment: I fully understand some questions are off-limits. I just do not see how that could possibly include questions about experience relevant for the job. I concur with other posters who point out the asker should make clear *why* that question is asked, to indicate whether they consider the subject of the question a good or a bad thing, for instance. But if the reasoning provided makes the candidate "seriously question working there", again, that's a *good* thing. As a candidate, I'm *glad* if I know what a prospective employer is up to and I can decide against them.

Comment: *the interviewee may think you are fishing for red-flags that would disqualify him. And of course he would find that very unjust.* Would "he"? (ಠ.ಠ)

Answer (score 8):

One could argue that a person that does not do programming as a hobby will turn up to work more refreshed than those that have spent all evening thinking about other software problems.

Also, is it any business of an employer what an employee does in his/her free time (as long as it is legal).

I have never been asked about hobbies in an interview. I would not ask either.

Comment: Maybe it's also a regional thing? I've never NOT been asked about hobbies :)

Comment: Definitely a "regional" thing. I've had HR departments tell me specifically NOT to ask about hobbies when I'm interviewing candidates, because they fear doing so will give the candidate fuel for a discrimination lawsuit ("you didn't hire me because I said I have X hobby which is somehow related to a protected class").

Comment: Sorry but being interested in side projects in your spare time does absolutely not imply that you will be more burnt out and less refreshed than someone who does not. What if that person who doesn't have a side project burnt themselves out playing badminton? Way too vague and assumptive of an argument to be making.

Comment: There is probably a strong correlation between the quality of a candidate and whether they do Github, open source projects, MeetUps. Can't see why its not valid to ask about these things.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it depends.

I would never ask this question when interviewing somebody for, say, an Architect, or Project Lead, or Business Analyst position.  How would *those* people ever replicate their work at home?

I might not ask every programmer. I have loved programming myself for my whole live, and have done it a lot privately. Today, for different reasons, there are long phases where I simply do not do it because there's no time or no need. So I understand if someone would not do it. I also understand that it's just a job for some, and don't judge them for it.

But sometimes, programmers or DevOps guys put out their enthusiasm for technology as a prime motivator for picking them. "I am so fascinated by this stuff that I would do everything to learn more / achieve more / bring the field further / ...". Frankly, if they pull this card, I find it very appropriate to ask them about their spare time.

This could be a honest-to-god question like "so, do you have some Linux box in your basement or something like that". If they go on to describe their HP ProLiant Nas4Free server, and are able to explain why XFS is a great thing, then I am happy and know for sure that they are fascinated. If they come up with nothing of the kind, then ... not so much. Even if they tell me that they ordered some Arduino for €5 from China, but never got around to really using it, I am happy.

Recently I had someone who was almost manic about some technology stuff related to cloud, DevOps etc.; he repeatedly told, with glee in his eyes, how he creates these complex servers for his own use. I asked him what he did exactly; he told me he setup a private mail server. I asked him what software he used and... he could not tell me. To say the least, that was not a happy incident for him. So he basically started a Free Tier AWS account (which takes roughly zero knowledge and effort) and spun up some premade mail server thingy. I did not pursue this further, but it did not gel well with coming over as an exuberant tech lover to me.

Comment: I'm a Business Analyst who has a side project (an open-source side project, no less!) relevant to my job. But I admit that's a rare case.

Comment: If you mention it during the interview, you can be pretty sure that I'll be all over it, @Charles. ;)

Answer (score 6):

While I would agree that there is nothing wrong with asking about side projects a candidate is working on. **Asking *"How many hours..."* can imply that you already assume they are doing something like this.** The risk here is that you make the candidate feel like they won't be a good fit in your company if they answer with *"Not much"* or *"I don't do any programming outside of work"*.

As a developer myself, if you bring up the discussion of hobbies or outside interests, any developer who does activities similar to their work life in their personal time will make mention of it. From here, it would not be unusual to ask how much they do. Bear in mind that some candidates are simply incapable of taking on personal projects due to obligations such as family, travel, other hobbies etc. By all means, ask if they spend time on open-source projects but keep in mind that an answer of *"zero"* should not be a black mark. The technical test is usually how you can find out if they are keeping their skills up to scratch.

Answer (score 4):

It is appropriate to ask if someone works on any development projects outside their course work/job and ask them to talk about it a bit. Be sure to not phrase it as a generic "so what are your hobbies?" kind of question; that would be inappropriate.

I've been in development for over twenty years and, in my experience, the best people work on something outside of work that is technically related. At a minimum, they listen to some podcasts or attend user groups to keep them abreast of changing technologies.

That said, I personally don't think it is a necessity that people practice their craft outside of working hours, but if I had two people interview that were identical in every other way, the person bettering themselves professionally would get the position.

Not specifically related to this question, but I feel it warrants stating:

As an interviewee, if you are offered a position and you do any "outside work" or plan to , be very sure to read the terms of employment. My last company had a clause stating they owned anything I developed outside of work (so I simply did not develop outside of work). And many companies take a position that you can moonlight, but anything you create with their resources (their computer, licensed software and so on) are their property.

Comment: My company cares about education. We have reading circles and have a budget for it. That includes the provision of text books, and hour per week reading/group chat. We also have tech talks once a week lasting between 15 - 30 mins. Also periodically we have hackathons - where we get the afternoon to develop something new, have free pizza and beer and then a bit more time before doing a small presentation.

Comment: @EdHeal I'd love to see that as a specific question on the next Stack Overflow developer survey. https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/ "How does your company contribute to your professional development?"

Comment: You can also ask the new employer for an exemption on a specific hobby project that you are already working on. Did this once and they were happy to grant it.

Answer (score 4):

Going off my experience, I say ask only if your company uses a lot of open source software or provides open source.

At my company, we have a lot of open source repos available on github and one of the questions asked during interviews is what sort of personal hobbies they do outside of work that involves coding. Having open source or a github account with a lot of pull requests for open source repos are a huge plus.

Nobody seemed bothered by the question as my company put that on the job posting as well as explaining that they are into open source code.

Comment: Surely if your company uses open source, and any improvements through your job, you should put back into the open source project. This could be the day-to-day part of the job

Comment: Right, also it shows that you are into collaboration and criticism of your code during pull requests to match coding standards set forth. Something that is very typical in open source projects that generally require a RFC, pull request, unit tests, review by someone, and so forth. By having a PR accepted, especially for a big project, shows that you are a better team player, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Ask them if they have experience with or contributed to Open Software, but stay away from questions about how many hours or if it was done outside of work.

The Open Software aspect of the question is fair game, it would be no different than asking if they were familiar with Linux or Git or eclipse or various other tools.  If your company uses certain Open tools, then experience with those would be a plus, less training.  If your company encourages, supports, limits, or prohibits Open software, this would be a good time to work it into the conversation.

But asking the prospective hire what they do on their spare time would be if anything, too intrusive, kind of over the line.  People are hired for what they can do at work, not for what they do outside of it.  Some companies limit what you can do outside of work, anything that might be considered illegal or competitive, you should get that out front, but remember that while interviewing someone, they are interviewing you, and are deciding if yours is a company that they would like to work at.  If you come across as wanting to limit or track what they do, outside of work, a lot of good people will go elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to avoid this line of questions, unless the candidate brings it up by himself. If you want to try to trigger such a discussion, ask about whether he has some publicly available code, this code might be hobby stuff, or it might be a paid work he has done.

As someone who contributed in all kind of ways to many OSS projects, I would be very annoyed if anyone brings it up as something that sounds like a requirement. When I contribute, I do it as a **hobby**, I do not apply the same development standards that I will apply to paid jobs. In addition there is a huge difference between working solo on a project and navigating the intricate web of a workplace. Working solo you do not need to be polite to co-workers, suffer the BS from marketing and be nice to the boss.

As other answers implied,this kind of question line will help you discover if someone likes coding as a hobby, and has the time for it, nothing more than that. Unless it is a very high profile project in which the candidate has a major role, the participation in OSS projects by itself will not help you know if his code is any good, nor if he can fit well in a work enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

In my country (Netherlands) this is one of the most common questions asked during an interview; mostly in the form of "What do you do to keep your skills up to date and keep learning (in your spare time)".

Basically they want to know what blogs you read, groups you follow or how often you spend time leaerning things. Of course it doesn't have to be for an open source project, what about just learning new languages/frameworks?

As long as you ask the question in a pretty open and friendly tone I assume you'll be fine, and I usually expect this question.

Comment: I agree. This is a completely open question that gets to the same facts whilst linking it to the candidate's own desire to keep up to date in a changing technology landscape

Answer (score 3):

People have pointed out how this question is discriminatory and I agree with that. **I also want to point out that looking for people who are programming outside of work does not necessarily make them motivated to do your work.** In my experience, it often can have just the opposite effect. They are so interested in their private projects that they pay more attention to them and less attention to the boring old business work. Or they are so tired that they can't focus properly because they stayed up til 3 am doing this cool thing. In any event, programming as a hobby after programming for work in not, in the long run, healthy. It is a major cause of burnout.

It is a problem in our industry that people do not have the time to train for changing technology at work. If you want to be a good place, you give them that time built in as part of the work. There is no other profession where you are expected and encouraged to spend all your time working. It is bad for the company (tired workers are not good workers), it is bad for the individual, it is bad for the profession (this is one of the major factors why people leave the profession early). Your assumption that this is a positive is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that asking this question really show intrinsic motivation and tendency to perform great on the job.

This question is not inappropriate, it is similar to ask "What are your hobbies outside of work ?"

But as Sabine stated, it can lead to some misunderstanding, as the interviewee may not understand if doing open source project is a good thing or a bad thing in the interviewer mind.

I want to add that people who have personal side-project are not better or more motivated than the one that do not.

As an example, I know some really great developper and mentor at work that spend their evening and week end with their family doing other activities. I also know a really great developer from school who is invested in a lot of open source project. He can't stop changing company because they are not a good fit for him, as his standard can be very high.

**To conclude**, the question can be great to discuss with the interviewee about what he likes to do, but should not be taken as an exclusive condition for acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

Asking about hours specifically would be inappropriate, asking if the person has worked on outside projects or independent work would have value, as would asking about volunteer projects.

Be aware, however that some companies have moonlighting clauses and clauses that anything developed during employment is considered company property, so the question may not be as productive as one might think.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. *If* the applicant is passionate about hobbyist programming, and *if* the company doesn't tolerate that/will claim ownership, the interview would be an excellent occasion to bring this possible dissonance up. Of course, nothing stops the interviewer from prefacing the question with something like "Some of our employees are also active in their own programming side projects in their spare time".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Right, because saying "I'm passionate but I'm not allowed to develop" would be so useful to gauge someone's passion.... wut?

Comment: Ok, I was seeing this from the applicant's perspective. I usually ask in interviews about the possibility of doing side projects, because if I already know up-front it's not going to be allowed, I can save both them and myself the time of going any further if I end up declining anyway. Of course, some people who like doing hobbyist projects might already have got caught in a situation where they cannot, but then, they can still mention this and outline what they used to do before entering their current, restrictive contract.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's a good practice.  I've absolutely walked away from loony contracts.  One company tried to get me to sign a non-compete clause AFTER I signed on

Answer (score 1):

A different wording, for all the reasons above:

- "Have you ever worked on a software project that wasn't part of a paid job?"

and then follow up with:

- How did you get into that?
- How did it go?
- What did you accomplish?

These will probably set a relaxed frame, because it's clear it's about the past, or now, or any time, so it's not probing current or planned activities. This should remove the "threat/worry" element.

**Then** you can probe for what you're actually after, indirectly:

*If no*:

- You've only ever coded within a job? [Asked in a curious tone, not a critical one]
- Do you do much with computers on your own clock?
- A lot of people get into software as hobbyists, then become professionals. Your path was slightly different...?

*If yes*:

- That sounds interesting!
- Follow that with: What kinds of projects did you get into? What accomplishments are you proudest of? Were these solo endeavours or group projects? And perhaps if you feel appropriate, *then* Do you still do it?
- Some of the best programmers we've had, also have their own projects on the side. Is coding something that you keep at work, or do you have a hobbyist focus too? [And same questions as above]

This approach hopefully reassures that it's seen positively, but avoids cuing them about an "expected" answer they need to be careful with.

Mainly , be careful to present it as interest and a possible positive, by the "angle" you take (and equally, by the angles you avoid!).

Avoid like the plague, any questions that could be taken as probing dedication to the job, such as "How do you balance a hobby like that, with work?" or "How much time do you give it". Perhaps think through your questions beforehand to be sure they are ones that will not come over wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate to ask a software developer about extra hours spent for side projects and open-source (as a hobby)?

I feel that it can **sometimes** be appropriate.  However, that entirely depends on the context of what position you're hiring for and what sort of candidates you're looking for.  And it doesn't seem appropriate *in your case*.

If you're looking for a self-starter with no previous career experience whose dream is to get into software development (because they love programming), then it's clearly a good sign that they're working toward that in their spare time.  And it lets them justify their resume full of unrelated jobs, and/or how they hope to move from part-time unrelated work to a full-time career job.  This is one way to get a junior level developer.

However, you say that you're looking

> for software developers positions (intermediate-senior level).

At that level, people should have years in the industry, including most likely crunch time, overnight deployments, etc.  You expect that they're already working full-time (or more) doing software development.  By that stage of life, they are likely to have other commitments outside of work.

For that role, a strong yes answer could be a red flag.  Someone who pushes themselves too hard could be burning out and hoping to avoid it by changing jobs.  But that's not going to happen if they keep it up, and you could seem to be encouraging it.  That wouldn't be good for either of you.

There are better questions for intermediate-senior level that could still address your concern of finding out about intrinsic motivation.  Ask about things that they no longer get to work with but enjoyed/miss, and things that they'd like to learn about or work with, but haven't had the chance yet.  Ask about which things they've done that they were particularly proud of or happy with, or for which they got praise or thanks that made them feel really good.

Answers could come from hobby work or from their day-job work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about any questions relating to how people spend their out-of-working hours time because what people do outside working hours is strongly correlated with gender. Consider that for some candidates the answer might be "No, I don't do any programming in my spare time, I'm far too busy looking after my young children / my aged parents".

If you're looking for programmers who do nothing but programming at any hour of the day, then you're probably not going to hire any women.

Comment: Based on my experience, this is precisely the reason why this question is often asked. It is intended to exclude most women.

Comment: I dont see what it has to do at all with gender. There are plenty of women that chose to program in their free time and if they chose not too then thats their personal choice and has nothing to do with their gender. Likewise most men are also just as busy looking after kids or parents.

Comment: It's called indirect discrimination. If you select candidates using criteria that are more commonly found in one gender than another, and that have no direct bearing on ability to do the job, then you are discriminating in a way that in many countries is illegal (and is always bad practice, since you want to get the best people you can).

Answer (score 1):

**Have you though about it in the opposite way?** People who do side projects maybe do them because the projects at their work are not interesting, use old technologies, or are just plain boring. Having employees do side projects probably means they are not really happy with their work projects (ie they don't fullfill them or they don't learn anything new while doing it.)

It may also mean that the person likes coding alone, and doesn't like to work with other people/in a team, which would again probably be a red flag.

**I like doing my side project because I got to choose what I am doing. I don't like to do projects for others that are not personally interesting to me.** But hey, you gotta pay the bills, so I am working on someone elses project although I'm not really motivated to do so. Trust me, if developers would get good money from side projects, nobody would work for other companies.

Its a completely wrong assumption that someone is better in any way if they do side projects. Besides, if I had a hard day at work coding, the last thing I want to do is come home and do coding again.